# Node on Raspberry Pi and connection via web3.js

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, raspberry-pi, ethraspbian

I have installed a geth-node on raspberry pie. Raspberry pie is connected via Ethernet.  Now  I am trying to connect to this node via web3.js

```
    var ethWeb3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://192.168.0.220:8042'));
```

192.168.0.220 ->is the address of device. (I connect so via terminal)

But if I check ethWeb3.isConnected(), it returns false.

My geth script is:

```
geth --identity "node1" --fast --networkid 42 --datadir /home/pi/ChainSkills/node --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --unlock 0 --password "/home/pi/ChainSkills/node/password.sec" --ipcpath /home/pi/.ethereum/geth.ipc --dev
```

Where can be a mistake?

Comment: I connect to web application, where I try to run web3.js, so:  localhost:9999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding when starting geth

```
--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0
```

Otherwise it's listening only on the `localhost`

```
geth --identity "node1" --fast --networkid 42 --datadir /home/pi/ChainSkills/node --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --unlock 0 --password "/home/pi/ChainSkills/node/password.sec" --ipcpath /home/pi/.ethereum/geth.ipc --dev
```